# get a count of users in all OUs and total the count

Tags: powershell, active-directory, get-aduser

there was a question posted along time ago about getting a count of users in an OU.  the answer to the questions was great (thank you Eric Nord) and I was able to use it to figure out most of what I need but I was hoping someone could help me figure out the final piece which is to total up the number of users.

here is the script to get the count.  I added the sort count to the end of the script

```
$root_ou = "ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com"
$User = get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase $root_ou -SearchScope Subtree | Select @{Name="OU";Expression={$_.distinguishedName -match "cn=.*?,OU=(?<OU>.*)" | Out-Null;$Matches.OU}}
$User | Group -Property OU | Select Name,Count | sort count
```

here is the output

```
 Name                                         Count
 
 Office 1,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com  1230
 Office 2,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com  390
 Office 3,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com  90
 Office 4,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com  10
```

what I need to figure out is how to then add a grand total count at the bottom like this

```
 Name                                          Count

 Office 1,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com   1230
 Office 2,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com   390
 Office 3,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com   90
 Office 4,ou=Users,ou=cmsg,dc=contoso,dc=com   10
 Grand Total                                   1720
```

thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following statement to construct and output an additional object that contains the overall user count:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'Grand Total'; Count = $User.Count }
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped; my pleasure, @NuckinFutz.